# Distinct cyclic permutation without Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

A [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/98649/106586) asks roughly the same as Dummit and Foote 2.3.9(e):

$S=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_p):x_i\in A\}$ for some set $A$ and $p$ prime. If $S$ has more than one distinct cyclic permutation, prove it has exactly p of them.

I believe the term cyclic permutation is meant to mean a cyclic shift of the whole tuple and not the more general meaning.

I understand the other solution that utilizes the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem.  I don't see that D&F mention this important theorem explicitly so was wondering if there is a simpler solution.  There is a solution [here](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/03/24/alternate-proof-of-cauchys-theorem/) but I don't follow his explanation either.